# Как задать максимальную длину значения для v-text-field с type='number'?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Как сделать максимальную длину значения для `v-text-field`?

С `type="number", maxlength` с этим типом не работает.

`<v-text-field  outlined type="number" @input="choice"></v-text-field>`

Answer (score 3):

`maxlength` для `v-text-field` можно добавить так:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="title"
    label="label"
    maxlength="20"
></v-text-field>
```

Можно расширить функционал, добавив `counter` и `rules`:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="title"
    label="label"
    maxlength="20"

    counter
    :rules="[rules.required, rules.counter]"
></v-text-field>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        rules: {
          required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
          counter: value => value.length <= 20 || 'Max 20 characters',
        },
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, но нужно было не рулсы добавить, а именно захардкодить , ограничить вводимое значение, но походу это не реально. Залезал под капот vuetify и да, это сделать нельзя. Баг от vuetify))

Comment: @Rodion во vuetify (1.5.х) есть маска:  mask="###.###.###-##", не спасает? или посмотрите в сторону https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask